# solve exception :no reverse match found

Tags: python, django

I got the error

> NoReverseMatch at /admin/myapp/leavdb11/6/change/ Reverse for 'emails'
>   with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['employee/emails/(\d+)/']

Answer (score 0):

If you are not capturing anything from url then you can use 
`'employee/emails/'`

Answer (score -1):

I also got that error once and I solved it by using proper name in urlpatterns.

Comment: name used in url patterns are correct.the problem is passsing id from views.py to templat,the template is used for sending email from admin to selected user.how can i solve this problem.